# Tkinter calendar module running very slow when pic date so many time ,

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

How can I run first my program when pic date in tkinter? Can I used other date module instead of tkinter calendar module or how can I type date in entrybox and add / / automatically

Comment: tkinter doesn't have a calendar module, so it's not clear what you're asking. Are you asking about the tkcalendar package?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it works for you.

```
    from tkcalendar import *

    start_date_entry = DateEntry(task1, selectmode="day",
                       date_pattern="mm/dd/yyyy",
                       selectforeground="red",
                       foreground='white',
                       normalforeground='green',
                       selectbackground="light blue")
```

Comment: i all ready used this, Ent_doj=DateEntry(root1,bg="BISQUE",textvariable=doj,width=11,locale='en_US', date_pattern='YYYY/mm/dd',font=("",9))
            Ent_doj.place(x=1115,y=35)
*** But when i run my program then this date module going to run slow the program, when is disable this date module then my program run fast and smooth